# ¿Cómo se escribe la expresión ".com"?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, símbolos, redacción

¿Cómo se escribe la expresión "punto com"?

Por ejemplo en esta frase:

> Pedro, debes tener tu marca, debes tener tu página web. ¿Dónde está tu nombre y apellido **punto com**?

¿Sería correcto escribirlo de esa forma?

Comment: Excelentes tus dos primeras preguntas. ¡Bienvenido al sitio y esperamos leerte muchas veces más! Recomiendo el [tour] por si quieres echar un vistazo a cómo funciona la comunidad.

Comment: Seguro que lo veré. Gracias, amigo. Este sitio es genial y responden rapidísimo. Definitivamente, haré más preguntas luego. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo apostaría por usar *.com* directamente en la escritura, como un todo, por lo que tu ejemplo quedaría en:

> Pedro, debes tener tu marca, debes tener tu página web. ¿Dónde está tu nombre y apellido .com?

---

Como justificación, encuentro este debate en [*los dominios .es*](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/los-dominios-es-246/), donde se preguntaba:

> El otro día dejaron de funcionar las direcciones de Internet acabadas en «.es». ¿Cómo podríamos expresar que fallaron? Se me ocurren tres posibilidades:
> —**Los dominios .es**
> —Los dominios punto es
> —Los dominios es
> ¿Convendría usar alguna tipografía especial (comillas, cursiva)?

Y desde Fundéu explicaron:

> **La primera fórmula es la más habitual** y no hay por qué considerarla incorrecta. Técnicamente, el dominio de nivel superior, que identifica el país o la actividad, no incluye el punto, pero cuando se habla de un conjunto de dominios se suele referir a todos aquellos que terminan en .es, .com, .net, etc., lo que justifica la inclusión del punto. A veces se ha hablado de las «punto com», pero es un sintagma que se refiere a las empresas relacionadas con Internet, no directamente a los dominios .com. No hace falta usar ningún estilo tipográfico especial.